# Why can't I put linear-gradrient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, gradient

This inst giving the background to my div. But if I take the linear away it gives the var value to it. Can't I give linear-gradients in jQuery?

```
var border_cor = 'red';
var border_cor2 = 'blue';

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.push_me').css({
    'background': 'linear-gradient(to right,' + border_cor + '50%,' + border_cor2 + ' 50%)'});
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing spaces between color and percentage.

Fixed example:

```
var border_cor = 'red'; var border_cor2 = 'blue';

$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.push_me').css({ 
    'background': 'linear-gradient(to right,' + border_cor + ' 50%,' + border_cor2 + ' 50%)'}); 
  });
```